# Do we need to add (require 'package_name.el) in init file if we installed packages with package manager?

Tags: emacs, require, alpha, package-managers

As titled , I'm confused whether we should add `(require 'package_name)` in init file if we have already used package manager rather than installed packages manually.

Some packages, like yasnippet or auto-complete, even if I don't add `(require 'yasnippet)`  it still works fine, but with package like `alpha` (a package in Marmalade), if I don't add `(require 'alpha)`, then Emacs cannot recognize the hot key `C->`, which is used to increase the transparency, and I get the error message `C-> is undefined`, so what is the `require` command actually doing and when should we add it?

Comment: Usually no. If the function you are calling is autoloaded you don't need to require the package.  You can check in the source, or via `C-h f <function-name>`. Instead of requiring you can add `(autoload '<function-name> "<source-file>")` to your init

Answer (score 0):

`require` *loads* the library in question, *unless* it had already been loaded.

Loading libraries takes time, so autoloading is often preferred, as this defers the load until it is needed.

package.el facilitates autoloading for ELPA packages in general, so *most* of the time you do not need to `require` these -- however it is ultimately dependent on (a) the package author, and (b) exactly how you are trying to use it.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe sounds simply like a packaging bug: i.e. that `alpha` package from Marmalade is poorly packaged.  `(require '<foo>)` should not change key bindings, for example, since `<foo>` might be loaded "by accident" for all kinds of reasons.

Instead it should probably define an `alpha-mode` minor mode which is autoloaded, so instead of `(require 'alpha)` you'd use `(alpha-mode 1)` (or the equivalent from Customize).